# Google Earth API for Flex/Flash

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, api, google-earth

are there any Flash/Flex API for Google Earth like the Map API? i haven't seen an API in Google earth API  official page. or is there any way to use all the features of its javascript API with actionscript/flex

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Flash API for Google Earth yet, just the GMaps Api.  They only have an Earth API for Javascript.

Comment: but i have seen google earth run on flash player so i am curious whether any other way to embed and use the features of Google earth..

Comment: I had to do research on this earlier this year and there is no Google Earth API for Flash, though I bet you can find an alternative that will allow similar GEarth Api functionality(i.e. KML mapping etc...)

Comment: it sounds like you are confusing Google Earth with Google Maps.  the only thing currently available is Google Maps API for Flash:  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/

Comment: That's what I meant in my original answer, GMaps Api is available for Flash, not Google Earth.

Comment: thank you very much for the comments finally i manage to use javascript API with adobe flex. :)

Comment: awesome, glad to have helped!